# recursively following values in a hash map clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, hashmap

I have a problem providing an edge case for the following recursive function that searches hash maps and other similar key,value storage.

```
(def hashbrownies
  {"Mary","Dave"
   "Dave","Anne"
   "Anne","Tim"})
```

current approach

```
(defn recursive-lookup
  [key-lst search-func conditional]
  (let [next-key (search-func (first key-lst))]
    (if (conditional next-key)
      (reverse key-lst)
      (recur (cons next-key key-lst) search-func conditional))))
```

examples that are working

```
>> (recursive-lookup ["Mary"] #(hashbrownies %) (partial = nil))
=> ("Mary" "Dave" "Anne" "Tim")

>> (recursive-lookup ["Mary"] #(hashbrownies %) #(< (.length %) 4))
=> ("Mary" "Dave" "Anne")
```

Problematic:

```
>> (recursive-lookup ["Mary"] #(hashbrownies %) #(> (.length %) 4))
=> NullPointerException   clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember (Reflector.java:296)
```

I can see what the problem is: as the condition can not be met, the function `#(> (.length %) 4)` takes `nil` (the last possible return value) as an argument. But being new to Clojure I am not sure how to cover for this. Is there an idiomatic way?

solution:

```
(defn recursive-lookup
  [key-lst search-func conditional]
  (let [next-key (search-func (first key-lst))]
    (if (or (nil? next-key)
            (conditional next-key))
      (reverse key-lst)
      (recur (cons next-key key-lst) search-func conditional))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle `nil` in your conditional function. You can use [fnil](https://github.com/nbeloglazov/clojure-interactive-tasks.git) for that. `fnil` replaces nil with some default value. So you can try:

```
(fnil #(> (.length %) 4) "")
```

If this conditional function receives `nil` it replaces `nil` with empty string "" and then call your function `#(> (.length %) 4)`.

Also you can use `count` instead `.length`. Count returns 0 for nil:

```
(count "123") => 3
(count nil) => 0
```

Comment: Nice, although if I get a default value or a 0, then the function will add that to the list and call itself again, running out of heap space. I think I need change the main function to return the list on any nil. perhaps a `case` statement?

Comment: Yes, I think you need to modify main function. You can add condition to `if`: `(if (or (nil? next-key) (conditional next-key)) ... )`